# NodeJS nodegui module could not be found

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Attempting to get [nodegui](https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui) running on a blank nodeJS project, but it won't run. The example [starter-project](https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui-starter) runs fine, however I do not want to use webpack on my project.

Error when running `node main.js`:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1208
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\Release\nodegui_core.node
�[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1208:18)�[39m
�[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)�[39m
�[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)�[39m
�[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)�[39m
�[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)�[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\�[4m@nodegui�[24m\nodegui\dist\lib\utils\addon.js:3:15)
�[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)�[39m
�[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)�[39m
�[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)�[39m
�[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)�[39m
```

main.js:

```
const { QMainWindow } = require("@nodegui/nodegui");

const win = new QMainWindow();
win.show();

global.win = win;
```

When running `npm install @nodegui/nodegui` [this](https://pastebin.com/BKqQPCat) is the output.

Windows 10 x64 build 18363, NodeJS version 12.16.1, NPM version 6.14.2, NodeGUI version 0.16.0

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Yes but I don't know what it was

Answer (score 1):

```
npx qode main.js
```

or

```
npm exec qode main.js
```

Answer (score -1):

It's seem specified module is missing in your project you need to run:

```
npm i --save specified
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue and I don't believe it's referring to an actual module named `specified`